# Why does this COUNTIF formula give 2?

Tags: excel-formula

I have this COUNTIF formula:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A20,A1:A20&"")
```

When I highlighted the formula and hit F9, I got the following array:

```
{1;2;2;1;1;1;1;1;1;2;2;2;1;2;4;4;4;4;1;1}
```

The formula by itself gives 2. I wonder from where the 2 come.

GDPXT01
GDPXT02
GDPXT02
GDPXT03
GDPXT04
PXQZW01
PXQZW02
PXQZW03
PXQZW04
OCCMD2
OCCMD2
DSOMR1
ITY
DSOMR1
PXQZW05
PXQZW05
PXQZW05
PXQZW05
BKXMA01
BKXMA02

Answer (score 0):

It is important to know what is data in `A1:A20`, but this is result of your function, it is array! For example, for this data-set below you will get same result.

1,
2,
2,
3,
4,
5,
6,
7,
8,
9,
9,
10,
11,
10,
12,
12,
12,
12,
13,
14

Answer (score 0):

We don't have clear understanding about your question unless see your excel sheet.
So I made some points that will helps for your understanding about COUNTIF function. COUNTIF, is used to count cells that match criteria.

```
=COUNTIF (range, criteria)


range - The range of cells to count.
criteria - The criteria that controls which cells should be counted.
```

Some Important Notes:

> COUNTIF is a function to count cells that meet a single criteria.
>   COUNTIF can be used to count cells with dates, numbers, and text that
>   match specific criteria. The COUNTIF function supports logical
>   operators (>,<,<>,=) and wildcards (*,?) for partial matching.

Some Examples:

```
=COUNTIF(D5:D12,">100") 
=COUNTIF(B5:B12,"jim")
```

Hope this might helps :)

Comment: I though giving array was better than giving the raw data. Apparently not. I have edited the question and added the raw data.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `COUNTIF` wrong.  As per [the documentation](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/countif-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34):

> `COUNTIF(range, criteria)`
>   **range** (required) - The *group* of cells you want to count
>   **criteria** (required) - *A* number, expression, cell reference, or text string that determines which cells will be counted.

This tells you that `Criteria` accepts only **one** value, and **not** a range/array.

If you use the "Evaluate Formula" tool, you will see that your criteria (`A1:A20&""`) *matches the current row*.  On row 1, it is treated as `A1&""`.  On row 2, it is treated as `A2&""`.  On row 15, it is treated as `A15&""`.  You can also put identical copies of your formula in every row, from 1 to 20, to see this.

As such - on rows 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, and 14 the result will be `2`.  On rows 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 13, 19, and 20 the result will be `1`.  And, on rows 15, 16, 17, and 18, the result will be `4`.

As a bonus, rows 21+ will give a result of `0`

Comment: I believe Microsoft claims that any Excel function can be turned into an array function. For example, ROW() accepts one variable. Yet, it can accept an array too, something like ROW(A1:A12). If COUNTIF can only accept one value, it should return an error, not a value like 2. Actually, you can find examples of COUNTIF accepting array as criteria. Please check out this web page: https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/count/count-duplicates-in-excel. You'll find this formula: =ROWS($A$2:$A$8)-SUM(IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$8,$A$2:$A$8) =1,1,0)). Both ROW and COUNTIF accept an array.

Comment: The result from the "Evaluate Formula" tool is exactly identical to the array I gave in the post. I am not sure what you were trying to say.

Comment: @Joehua If you want to use `CountIf` in an Array Formula, then A) You need to use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to convert it to an Array Formula, and B) You need to **DO SOMETHING** with the array: for example, wrap it in `SUM` - a Cell can only display a single value, not an Array.  The value it displays will, by default, match the row that you are on

Comment: Thanks. You answered my question. Here is what I am looking for : "The value it displays will, by default, match the row that you are on." The formula happened to be on the row that the formula returned 2. So, 2 was what I see. The formula could have returned 1 or 4 if it had sit on other row.